# Print PDF from BLOB

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Im getting a PDF file from and external API, using this code I can download the file correctly:

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open("POST", url, true);
    req.responseType = "blob";
    req.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    req.send(data);

    req.onload = function (event) {
       var blob = req.response;
       var link=document.createElement('a');
       link.href=window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
       link.download="receipt_" + new Date() + ".pdf";
       link.click();
    };
```

**But what I really need is to print the file without open it**, I tried something like

```
window.open(window.URL.createObjectURL(blob));
window.print();
```

But when do this way the file does not show correctly, It shows something like this:

```
PDF-1.7
%����
6 0 obj
<< /Type /Page /Parent 1 0 R /LastModified (D:20201027223421-03'00') ... bla bla
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Shouldn't print be invoked on the new window, not the current window?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I have already solve this using:

```
req.onload = function (event) {
    var blob = new Blob([req.response], {type: 'application/pdf'}); //this make the magic
    var blobURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

    iframe =  document.createElement('iframe'); //load content in an iframe to print later
    document.body.appendChild(iframe);

    iframe.style.display = 'none';
    iframe.src = blobURL;
    iframe.onload = function() {
      setTimeout(function() {
        iframe.focus();
        iframe.contentWindow.print();
      }, 1);
    };
};
```

Comment: This is causing `Uncaught NS_ERROR_FAILURE: ` on FireFox

Comment: Tried many solutions, and finally found the real solution. Thanks bro!

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below to make sure the .pdf file is correct. Verify the pdf with the preview that opens.

```
    <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>MDN Example</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function closePrint () {
  document.body.removeChild(this.__container__);
}

function setPrint () {
  this.contentWindow.__container__ = this;
  this.contentWindow.onbeforeunload = closePrint;
  this.contentWindow.onafterprint = closePrint;
  this.contentWindow.focus(); // Required for IE
  this.contentWindow.print();
}

function printPage (sURL) {
  var oHiddFrame = document.createElement("iframe");
  oHiddFrame.onload = setPrint;
  oHiddFrame.style.position = "fixed";
  oHiddFrame.style.right = "0";
  oHiddFrame.style.bottom = "0";
  oHiddFrame.style.width = "0";
  oHiddFrame.style.height = "0";
  oHiddFrame.style.border = "0";
  oHiddFrame.src = sURL;
  document.body.appendChild(oHiddFrame);
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
  <!-- <p><span onclick="printPage('externalPage.html');" style="cursor:pointer;text-decoration:underline;color:#0000ff;">Print external page!</span></p> -->
 
</body>
</html>

<script>
 req.onload = function (event) {
   var blob = req.response;
   var link=document.createElement('a');
   let srcPdf =window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
   printPage(srcPdf)
};

</script>
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Printing