# How to open blobURL and print automatically?

Tags: javascript, angular, pdf, syncfusion

I have the codes to open the blobURL in a new window but I want it to open the print window automatically without having to click on the print button. Please advise. The current code is now printing the old window which is not what I want to print. Id want to print the new window which is the pdf file.

```
                    var pdfExpComplete = (args) => {
                        args.promise.then((e) => {
                            var blobURL = URL.createObjectURL(e.blobData);
                            window.open(blobURL);
                            window.print(blobURL);
                    });

                   $scope.pdfExpComplete = function (args) {
                      args.promise.then(function (e) {
                      var blobURL = URL.createObjectURL(e.blobData);
                      window.open(blobURL);
                      });
                   };
```

Comment: This answer might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64576204/13231807

Answer (score 1):

We can open the bloburl and print the document automatically by using the below code snippet, please try the below code and let us know the result.

```
var blobURL = URL.createObjectURL(e.blobData);
window.open(blobURL).print();
```

https://www.syncfusion.com/kb/11941/how-to-open-a-pdf-in-a-new-tab-or-download-a-pdf-document-using-ajax-call